# I am sending my UDP from my pc to another pc and vice versa, but can not receive

Tags: java, udp

I am sending my simple string values as UDP data from my pc to another pc(both we have proper java envroment and correct code) and vice versa, but either me and he can not receive the udp. my(and his) port forever waitng with loops from the udp data each of our pc, when other side send me, it can not received....all same port..

but when i send and receive local pc, it is no problem....

what's the problem here?

```
  try {     
       int port = 7776;
       byte[] msg = chattext.getText().getBytes();

       // Get the internet address of the specified host
       InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("124.126.176.80");//my pc`s ip adress

       // Initialize a datagram packet with data and address
       DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(msg, msg.length,
           address, port);

       packet.getPort();

       // Create a datagram socket, send the packet through it, close it.
       DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket();
       dsocket.send(packet);
       dsocket.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: You need to post the receive code as well

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is pretty much guesswork, but..

The problem is probably on the receiving side. You are listening on localhost and not on the interface's IP adresses or a wildcard IP address so you won't receive any packets from the outside world.

Comment: ok, thank you, for your reply... how can solve this problem? localhost is listening from remote side send me udp, but he send to my ip address , but i can not receive? so how can i do that to receive>

Comment: i am wait from my pc to receive other pc`s sent dup, i gave it my ip address,,,but i can not receive his sent udp...so how can i solve? thanks..

Comment: check with tcpdump or wireshark that the machine actually receives the datagrams. if not, it's a firewall issue. if it does check how do you *receive* those datagrams.

Comment: yi_H:  how can listen my ip address`s port to receive udp from outside?

Comment: sorry but your are *not* listening (lol), and because of that just wasting other people's time.